# Error "illegal variable type for this position " in prolog

Tags: visual-prolog

I try to make a search of animal, who has this property, but I have an error "illegal variable type for this position ".How to solve it?

```
domains
type=symbol
object=symbol
property=symbol
value=symbol
parent=symbol
predicates
nondeterm is_a(type, parent) 
nondeterm has_prop(object, property, value) 
nondeterm has_property(object, property, value) 
clauses
is_a(dog,wolf).
is_a(dingo,wolf).
is_a(wolf,volki).
is_a(coyote,volki).
is_a(jackal,volki).
is_a(volki,dogs).
is_a(fox,dogs).
is_a(arctic_fox,dogs).

has_prop(dogs, travel, walk). 
has_prop(dogs, food_for_child, milk).  
has_prop(volki, size, medium). 
has_prop(volki, color, brown). 
has_prop(arctic_fox, color, white). 
has_prop(arctic_fox, size, small). 
has_prop(fox, color, orange). 
has_prop(fox, size, small). 
has_prop(wolf, color, grey). 
has_prop(wolf, size, large). 
has_prop(dog, color, brown). 
has_prop(dog, size, small). 
has_prop(dingo, color, orange). 
has_prop(dingo, size, medium). 



has_property(Object, Property, Value):-
has_prop(Object, Property, Value). 
has_property(Object, Property, Value):-
is_a(Object,Parent), 
has_property(Parent, Property, Value).

goal
has_property(X,size,medium).
```

I have an error "illegal variable type for this position " at this line:

```
is_a(Object,Parent),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in types and variables. I delete domains and work with simple types.

Right Code:

```
predicates
nondeterm is_a(symbol, symbol) 
nondeterm has_prop(symbol, symbol, symbol) 
nondeterm has_property(symbol, symbol, symbol) 
clauses
is_a(dog,wolf).
is_a(dingo,wolf).
is_a(wolf,volki).
is_a(coyote,volki).
is_a(jackal,volki).
is_a(volki,dogs).
is_a(fox,dogs).
is_a(arctic_fox,dogs).

has_prop(dogs, travel, walk). 
has_prop(dogs, food_for_child, milk).  
has_prop(volki, size, medium). 
has_prop(volki, color, brown). 
has_prop(arctic_fox, color, white). 
has_prop(arctic_fox, size, small). 
has_prop(fox, color, orange). 
has_prop(fox, size, small). 
has_prop(wolf, color, grey). 
has_prop(wolf, size, large). 
has_prop(dog, color, brown). 
has_prop(dog, size, small). 
has_prop(dingo, color, orange). 
has_prop(dingo, size, medium). 


has_property(O, Property, Value):-
has_prop(O, Property, Value). 
has_property(O, Property, Value):-
is_a(O,Parent), 
has_property(Parent, Property, Value).

goal
has_property(X,size,medium).
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have Visual Prolog available for testing, so I'm not really sure about the solution, but I think the problem is that you should make clear that `domains` and `predicates` elements are *ground* terms.
So I suggest to either make them lowercase, or bracket them with hyphens, otherwise they are *variables*:

```
domains
 type=symbol
 object=symbol
...

predicates
 is_a(type, parent) 
...
```

or

```
domains
 'Type'=symbol
 'Object'=symbol
...

predicates
 is_a('Type', 'Parent') 
...
```

*edit*

If you have SWI-Prolog available, just comment out from start of file to `domains` included. Or see [this notebook](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/XoMzIeIJ.swinb) on SWISH.

Comment: After this changes, I don't have an error, but I don't have a solution too. I think they should be variables because I use inheritance. Then dingo inherits from wolf than have its properties.

Comment: They must be variables in `has_property/3` and `is_a/2`, of course. Indeed, I tested in SWI-Prolog (just remove the declarations) and I got `?- has_property(X,size,large).
X = wolf ;
X = dog ;
X = dingo ;
false.
`. AFAIK, inheritance doesn't play any role in Visual Prolog (well, was Turbo Prolog the last time I used it...).

Comment: What do you mean by "has_property/3 and is_a/2"? Or maybe you rewrite my code to easier understanding.

Comment: `has_property/3` it's the standard Prolog way to describe a predicate:`functor` (i.e. its name) and `arity` (i.e.  its num.of.arguments) separated by /.

Comment: Can you please, send me the code,because I'm trying to change it, but then have no solution

Comment: Have you tried the SWISH link ? the code is there. Just click the right triangle at bottom...

Comment: Ok, I  see it. But I need to make it into Visual Prolog. Are there ways to solve it?

Comment: I updated it. Now I don't have an error, but don't have solutions,  too.

Comment: note carefully the Uppercase variables from the SWISH link

Comment: I update code one more,but now I have my first error "illegal variable type for this position ".